# how to Convert base64 image path to real path using jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While image selection time the image path shows like (src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j) this how can i convert this to real path

Comment: from base64 string it is not possible it is just simple string of image. you should be able convert it to real image (binary) if that is the intention.

Answer (score 0):

This is full image source encoded in `base64`. That means there's no image file, or at least it isn't associated with this source in any way.